# is it possible to cache a local file to Nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, lua, memcached

I don't know it is relate with Nginx or not.
What I want to do is, my frontend web server is only running Nginx and there is a (Nginx-lua-modules)Lua script which is retrieving some data from backend server and save to a file on frontend web server.

Now I need to cache that file on memory for 60min or 24hr or etc.. but there is only Nginx is running.
So, is it possible to cache from Nginx through Lua script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can totally do it, but how you'd go about it totally depends on the size of the file. For something very small, a shared dictionary might be the easiest solution, but for something bigger you should maybe use something like memcached or redis instead.

Comment: The file is very small, so I think sharing dictionary may be the solution. 
Can you share me some information for this. By the way, i have already redis server but web server can't access to redis sever for some security reason.